# links in TYPO3 newsletter not working

Tags: hyperlink, typo3

A collegue is trying to send a newsletter through TYPO3 - this "worked before".

Now, in the newsletter editor the links look normal, however when sending a test email, it contains a link like

`http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=0123&rid=###SYS_TABLE_NAME###_###USER_uid###&mid=###SYS_MAIL_ID###&aC=###SYS_AUTHCODE###&jumpurl=0`

How toget "normal links"  here? I've looked around in the typo3 settings, but couldn't find anything that would work or even looked good. A quick glance at the newsletter extension documentaiton dind't help either. (I also know roughly nothing about TYPO3...)

Any suggestions?

[edit]  this affects only "Send preview", When sending to a recipient list, everythign works as expected. So - works for us, for now.

Comment: Is the software on site or hosted? If hosted perhaps there was an update that broke this. Have you contacted their support?

Comment: it works when sending the newsletter normally (the tokens are replaced with "useful" items, and we get a redirect to the page). Only the "send preview" did not work as expected / intended.